# How to Autofill Logical Formulas to a certain cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Two questions 1) Can I autofill logical formulas to a cell using VBA and how (there is something wrong with my code) and 2)Can I autofill it only when data is entered and how?

The formula I want to put works when I put into a a cell but not VBA:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",$A2)),"Scanner 2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",$A2)),"Scanner 1","Error"))
```

For the VBA I also used Relative Coordinates, did not work:

```
Range("C2").Value="=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('$',RC[-2])),'Scanner 2', IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('#',RC[-2])),'Scanner 1','Error'))"
```

Pictures that may help:

[image: Picture of VBA and debug highlighted!]

[image: Picture of Spreadsheet]

Comment: try `Range("C2").FormulaR1C1="=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('$',RC[-2])),'Scanner 2', IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('#',RC[-2])),'Scanner 1','Error'))"`

Comment: No, adding .Formula or .FormulaR1C1 did not work

Comment: `Range("C2").formular1c1="=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",RC[-2])),""Scanner 2"", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""#"",RC[-2])),""Scanner 1"",""Error""))"`

Comment: Hi SJR Thank you so much , the double quotations rather than singles and .Formula instead of .Value worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a combination of the use of single quotes + you didn't add as `. Formula`:

So:

```
Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",$A2)),""Scanner 2"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""#"",$A2)),""Scanner 1"",""Error""))"
```

Should work

Also, I see in your code you are using `.Select`, there are many ways to avoid using this. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) link.

The below example will do the same thing:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C2:C100").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",$A2)),""Scanner 2"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""#"",$A2)),""Scanner 1"",""Error""))"
End With
```

You'll notice Excel will auto-adapt the formula to the correct cell references.

Comment: Thank you so much JvdV, greatly appreciate! Would you know how I can have this calculate or formula executed automatically  as i enter data into cell A?